# Programmatically Set Background Resource of EditText to transparent field

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-resources, android-drawable

This is the default way an EditText looks when I create one:

[image]

This is what it looks like after I change the background of it:

[image]

To change the background to the image above, I add the following EditText property to my EditText in my XML file:

```xml
android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
```

---

What I want to do is do what I've done above in my activity class (giving the user an option to select between the classic style and the transparent/new style).

So like this - I need people to fill in the `/*...*/`

```
if (classicTextbox()) { // the blocky white one

    editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);

} else { // the new transparent one

    editText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    editText.setBackgroundResource(/*...*/);
}
```

So how do I change it back to the new, transparent EditText style?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up trying to just save the original `Drawable` when the layout is opened and then set the background resource that way whenever I want. Like this:

In my `onCreate` method:

```
Drawable originalDrawable = editText.getBackground();
```

And then to set it:

```
// need to use .setBackground and .setBackgroundDrawable depending on the 
// android version because .setBackgroundDrawable is depreciated
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
int jellyBean = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN;
if(sdk < jellyBean) {
    editText.setBackgroundDrawable(originalDrawable);
} else {
    editText.setBackground(originalDrawable);
}
```

I still encourage more answers because I don't quite like this solution.

---

Sources:

[How to return to default style on EditText if I apply a background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912237/how-to-return-to-default-style-on-edittext-if-i-apply-a-background)

[setBackground vs setBackgroundDrawable (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947603/setbackground-vs-setbackgrounddrawable-android)

Answer (score 1):

The the default holo `EditText`'s background is: `edit_text_holo_dark`. That's the dark version. There is also the counterpart to that, the light version: `edit_text_holo_light`.

**`edit_text_holo_dark.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_default_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_disabled_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_activated_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_default_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_multiline="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_disabled_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_multiline="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_multiline_disabled_holo_dark" />

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_activated_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

Keep in mind that these holo elements are only available on Android HC+.

Comment: How can I access the holo drawables like I did with `android.R.drawable` ? I can't just copy that xml for myself because it makes references to drawables that I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void setBackground(View v, int backgroundColor, int borderColor) {
        GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
        shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 16, 16, 16, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
        shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
        shape.setStroke(3, borderColor);
        v.setBackground(shape);
    }
```

Not Exact Solution, But Alternative.