# What is the EditText background drawable resource name?

Tags: android

I am assigning an EditText a custom background, but then at some point I want to revert it back to its default native background asset. I am not sure what that asset is called though. I have tried:

```
@android:drawable/edit_text
```

but that gives me an EditText style that seems like it's from a very old version of android.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6912298/4385913)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the background property from the XML and that should be it