# How to display Edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText that looks like this:

[image: default editText]

When doing an action in the EditText the background is changed with the following code:

```
edtCampo.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

[image: editText with background]

Then another action is made and the EditText background is changed again with the following code:

```
edtCampo.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

[image: editText with transparent background]

The problem is that in the EditText I do not see the line below, what property should I give to make it look like the first image ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912237/how-to-return-to-default-style-on-edittext-if-i-apply-a-background

Comment: you can set view with background red color below your edit text which will be displayed as line ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
int backgroundResource = 0;
if(redBackgroundNeeded){
    backgroundResource = R.color.red;
}
view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);
```

Comment: No, the line below does not appear

Comment: I bet the problem is not in setting background or resource...

Comment: Don't you use some king of "holoeverywere" and initially set some 9patch image to textview to get the bottom line?

Comment: Also try to set some other color as a background. Yellow for example. Will the bottom line disappear when background will be set to Yellow or Transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use,

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
```

To achieve pro-grammatically,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    edt1.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.red));
}
```

Result,

[image]

Comment: how do I put the backgroundTint property in the java code?

Comment: see my updated code

Comment: Did not serve me